# configuring hadoop multi node using cloudera manager free edition

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

Can any one help me how to configure hadoop multi node using cloudera manager free edition?

I have 8 systems connected in network,

My requirement is one should be a name node,job tracker
one should be secondary name node
and 6 should be a data node

Pls help to configure

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic bullet to configure a Hadoop cluster easily. It takes some effort to setup a cluster. [Here](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/FREE45DOC/Cloudera+Manager+Free+Edition+Installation+Guide) is the documentation for setting up a Cloudera Cluster.